# Potential energy and particle collisions/decays

Tags: special-relativity, energy, particle-physics, potential-energy, collision

Why is it that the (possible) potential energy of particles is not taken into account when studying the available energy in particle collisions, or decays? By this, I mean that one simply uses the relativistic energy dispersion relation $E^{2}=m^{2}+p^{2}$ (in units where $c=1$) when calculating threshold energies, energy conservation and the like.

Is it simply that both collisions and decays occur at single points in spacetime (i.e. they are local), and since only the difference in potential energy is physical (in the context of special relativity), there is no potential energy that can be extracted to participate in the energy of the collision/decay? Or is there something else to it?

Comment: I'm frankly not sure what you are asking, but particle physics is done in the full awareness of and with the application of potential energy. Where did you get the idea that it is not?

Comment: @dmckee        Sorry, I have elucidated my question a little further. What I mean, is that one uses $E^{2}=m^{2}+p^{2}$ in such calculations, which makes no mention of potential energy.

Comment: Presumably you mean in the context of doing collision kinematics? The values are calculated when the particle are separated by significant distance meaning that the potential energies are negligible under the conditions of the calculation. Look, instead, at how one calculates the cross-section for Mott scattering. The Coulomb potential makes an explicit appearance.

Comment: @dmckee   Yes, you're right. I forgot that one treats the particles as asymptotically free. So when doing collision kinematics, is one just determining whether particles have enough initial energy to create new ones when they collide. This collision is usually assumed to happen over an infinitesimally small time interval. Is this why such calculations are valid in a lot of cases? Thanks for the reference, I'll take a look.